# JPA Exception "lastval() not supported" in Greenplum

Tags: jpa, greenplum

My code is running fine in Postgres, but when I switched to Greenplum, the following exception occurs：

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: lastval() not supported
Error Code: 0
Call: select lastval()
Query: ValueReadQuery(name="SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY" sql="select lastval()")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1620)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.performPreQueryFlush(QueryImpl.java:967)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:400)
    at module.AuthREST.login(AuthREST.java:103)
    ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: lastval() not supported
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:644)
```

This is User model class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

This is the code in AuthREST class:

```
...

@POST
@Path("login")
@Consumes({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
public Response login(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response,
        @FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormParam("password") String password) {

    request.login(username, password);
    ...
}
```

...

So how should i do avoid the exception in Greenplum?

Comment: You'll probably need to implement a greenplum dialect for EclipseLink or at least a new `GenerationType`, or avoid using sequences. Though `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` with a `@SequenceGenerator` might work depending on the implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

The way sequences work in Greenplum:

- the master has a "sequence server" running (if you look into the process list, you see a separate process)
- every time a segment needs the next value from a sequence, it connects to the master and asks for the next value (this is overhead, by the way: http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/SERIAL_Datatype_Performance_in_Greenplum_Database/ )

The underlaying problem: the sequence server does not keep tab on the requests from the segment servers, therefore it does not know the last value (or values) per segment. Hence lastval() cannot be answered.

Even if the sequence server keeps a log of assigned sequence values: the way your query works, lastval() is executed on the master - but the master never actually inserted any data.

tl;dr: Retrieving the last value of a sequence in Greenplum is problematic. Even if lastval() is supported, the returned answer is likely not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Reference your sequence table using sql `last_value` column. You can create your own last value function.

Example:

```
Select last_value from wcdl_dictionary.sq_dic_table_definition_table_id
```